# CSS Print Media: page-break-before is breaking page but not in correct position

Tags: css, printing

I am using google chrome to print a page, I have multiple layouts, each layout has one h2 tag and a svg element. each layout is within a div with class page with style

```
.page {
    page-break-after: always;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

it breaks the page but not in the correct location. the h2 tag of the second layout is before the next page which was supposed to be in the next page. in some cases even the svg element is placed in two pages but i have its css set to

```
svg {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

What am i missing here?
Note: 
I have set *float: none;* to all parent element.
I tried to upload the layout image but i cant as i dont have enough points.

Comment: This works perfectly for me... I tried this: http://codepen.io/thomasbormans/pen/MwRNar

Comment: I think i am having problem because of angular material design css, i just copied my html and put it with plain css, and it works, thanks.